# Web API works locally but doesn’t work on azure

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-web-app-service

I have created a web API connected to azure sql server in .net core using visual studio for Mac .  Then I created a web app in azure and then published by project directly in visual studio for Mac to azure.

After I published I try to access the api using postman and chrome (URL/api/menu) but I got 500 server error which is generic and doesn’t tell me anything.

In visual studio for Mac I got the green light it said published and directly took me to the new url.

So, what do you guys thing is the problem.

This is my first time using azure so I didn’t change any setting or anything

Comment: Does it work when debugging in your local? Try to debug local to check the detail error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since many different problems can cause this error page, I can strongly recommend the following in order to determine the root cause quickly and easily, without struggling with Azure (or any server/platform for that matter) to get logs.

You can enable extremely helpful error messages at startup by setting the .`UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")` and `.CaptureStartupErrors(true)` actions in your `Program.cs` file.

For ASP.NET CORE 2.1

```
public class Program  
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
            .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Add these commands in your startup.cs class:

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
app.UseBrowserLink();
```

also enable stdoutLog in your web.config file

```
stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
```

Error code 500 in web api,usually, means problems with a configuration in Startup.cs - the most common problems include an issue with DB itself, an issue with migrations (if you are using Code First approach), problems with appsettings.js.

Please refer to the log file in .\logs\stdout.

Hope it helps.